# preg_match a programming string

Tags: php, regex

what I want is a regular expression that matches a php string. So that means everything between `"` and `"`, excluding the `\"`. My expression until now has been

`/"([^\"]*)"/As`

but that one is not correct. For example with this string

`"te\"st"`

it matches `"tes\` whilst it should match `"te\"st"`. I also tried this one:

`/"([^\"].*)"/As`

which matches the above string correctly, yet when I have this string `"te\"st""` it matches `"te\"st""`, whilst it should only match `"te\"st"`

Any help appreciated!

Comment: are you parsing php code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the regex you want:

```
(?<!\\)"(?:\\\\|\\"|[^"\r\n])*+"
```

I can make you a shorter variation, but it will not be as solid.

See [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/34).

**Explanation**

- The negativelookbehind `(?<!\\)` asserts that what precedes is not a backslash
- match the opening quote
- `(?:\\\\|\\"|[^"\r\n])` matches a double backslash, an escaped quote `\"` or any chars that are not quotes and newline chars (assuming a string on one line; otherwise take out the `\r\n`)
- `*` repeats zero or more times and the `+` prevents backtracking
- `"` matches the closing quote

To use it:

```
$regex = '/(?<!\\\\)"(?:\\\\\\\\|\\\\"|[^"\r\n])*+"/';
if (preg_match($regex, $yourstring, $m)) {
    $thematch = $m[0];
    } 
else { // no match...
     }
```

Comment: It does seem to work, could you perhaps explain why it works?

Comment: Added explanation, let me know if you have questions. :)

Comment: @MightyPork Are you serious? See [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/33). What should match matches. What shouldn't match does not match.

Comment: Oh yeah? How about `"a\\"bc"` ? Mine fails, but yours fails at this too! (matches it where it shall not)

Comment: Thanks a lot. What would I have to change to make `"test\\"` match?

Comment: Just add `four slashes |` as one of the options in the alternation. Just edited the answer to allow that. :)

Comment: Updated the demo, explanation and code. Let me know if you have more questions. :)

Comment: @MightyPork You are right, my pattern didn't handle double backslashes, which were not in the spec. Added it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```
/\A"(?>[^"\\]+|\\.)*"/s
```

in php code you must write:

```
$pattern = '/\A"(?>[^"\\\]+|\\\.)*"/s';
```

pattern details:

```
\A     # anchor for the start of the string
"
(?>    # open an atomic group (a group once closed can't give back characters)
    [^"\\]+   # all characters except quotes and backslashes one or more times
  |
    \\.       # an escaped character
)*
"
/s     singleline mode (the dot can match newlines too)
```

Comment: Thanks! This one does match `\"test"` though, when it shouldn't. The string should always start with a `"`

Comment: @user3828747: with a " at the start of the string ?

Comment: Yes, the string should always start with a `"`. Yours allows the string to start with `\"` I think

Comment: @user3828747 It depends on whether you want to be able to match these strings anywhere within a larger string (which is what I assumed), or just match the string when it is the only thing in the input. In this case, the `A` flag used by Caz works, and you don't have to worry about `\"`

Comment: @zx81: I just add it and I wondered, "but why zx81 have putted a lookbehind at the begining?"

Answer (score 0):

This one matches it:

```
/"((?:.*?(?:\\")?)*)"/As
```

**Try it [live](http://regex101.com/r/eO6kN8/1)!**

What it does:

any number of times, repeat `.*?` and optional `\"`. So it matches all possible scenarios.

Comment: Nah, you need the look behind like in mine, otherwise you match `"abc"` in `\"abc"`

Comment: That's BS, it doesn't match `\"dfh"` at all.

Comment: fails on "a\\"a" <- only a\\ should be matched as \ is escaping another \ here

Comment: `That's BS` It's the second time this week that you're abusive in answer to my comments. Not downvoting you, but someone else might. Here is [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/32), see for yourself. That string should not match.

Comment: @zx81 you are not using my pattern in the demo.

Comment: Of course I'm using your pattern. I pasted it from you. Unless you mean the `A` flag, which shouldn't be there if you want to be able to match these strings in the middle of any text.

Comment: alright, I admit my pattern is broken. But I won't attempt to fix it now, when yours is accepted.